# C++ this->serialPort1->Write() error

Tags: serial-port, c++-cli

```
 unsigned char Hex[] = {0xff,0x01};
....
this->serialPort1->Write( Hex, 0, 2);  //(error)
```

The array as you can see is not ascii, but hex bytes.  The write() allows for byte arrays in addition to strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

yet this fails and the error claims that Hex needs to a pointer to a string.

I'm using MS VS 2013 and C++.
What am I missing?

Comment: Change `unsigned char` to `char` or use an appropriate cast.

Comment: The data being written is binary not ascii.  According to MS, if the data is ascii it will be encoded as such and anything greater than 0x7f will be altered.  Hence it must remain as raw unmolested bytes=unsigned chars=hex bytes.   I assume since they use write() for both strings and byte arrays, that the compiler interprets the type of the pointer to determine whether to treat the array as a string or as an array of unsigned chars.  Please click the link provided to see what I mean.

Comment: You are not writing C++ code.  This is C++/CLI, you **must** use the proper array type.  Use the `array<>` keyword.

Comment: Hans, how is that written then?  array<unsigned char> Hex[] = {0xff,0x01};   I don't have it right, as that does not work

Comment: I changed it to array<unsigned char>^ Hex = gcnew array<unsigned char>(2);  And the errors have gone away.  But now how do I initialize the array in that same statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use C++/CLI, then change your code to:

```
array<unsigned char> ^Hex = {0xFF, 0x01};
// ....
serialPort1->Write(Hex, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using C++/CLI, do yourself a huge favor and use the Windows serial port API, not the .NET SerialPort class.

[These are the Win32 functions for serial port configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Besides those, you use the usual file API (`CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`).

I'm in the process of writing a blog series explaning why the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class should be avoided and the better way using the Win32 API directly, the first article is [here](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Comment: I did not know I was using CLI.  I started with MS visual studio and thought I was writing in C++.   Apparently to use the serialPort1->Write() function, I have to create parameters using CLI.  Leave it to MS to make this overally complicated.   Looking forward to your blog

Comment: A downvote, but you couldn't think of a single suggestion on how to improve this explanation? Or some basis for disagreement?